# Can I safely connect batteries to an AC-powered device?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ac

Let’s say I have a device, and on the box that goes into the wall it says “9V DC.” If I understand correctly, this means that it modulates the electricity coming in from the wall so that the appliance gets just 9V of electricity, and it also ensures that the current flows through as a direct current rather than an alternating one.

Can I just take a 9V battery and use electrical tape and copper wires to connect it to this cable? Do I need to be careful about which prong I tape to which wire (and what happens if it’s a 3-prong appliance instead of just 2)? Or will I risk blowing my device? If I can’t use 9V, what is the maximum that I am able to use?

Comment: Depends what the device is, whether it operates on AC or DC, etc.  What are the specs of the device in question?  Are you just curious or do you have reason to want to power the device from battery?

Comment: It is also not completely clear from your phrasing whether the device is a power supply or a load, although I'm leaning towards load.

Comment: Not sure if by “cable” you mean the cable that plugs into the wall or the output of the power supply... As for the “lower battery voltage” - do you mean “minimum”?

Comment: No wall socket gives 9V AC, so there's a power supply somewhere that you haven't described.  A power supply could give 9V AC, or 9V DC.  It's usually on the label, though often as a symbol rather than words.

Comment: @KH I’ve edited as much as I can. I’m not sure what you mean by “power supply” versus “load.”

Comment: @SolarMike Edited.

Comment: @SimonB Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add some info I think may help you.  I infer that if you are going to the trouble of asking, you have some device(s) that you would actually like to produce a battery power option for.  You can do this for most devices, but doing so without knowledge may destroy a device in some cases, so unless you can reverse engineer it or obtain information about the power it requires, there is some risk.

Just as a few examples, some devices can be destroyed by receiving too high a voltage or current for tiny amounts of time.  Some can be destroyed by not receiving enough voltage, most by too much.  Some are sensitive in the same ways, but more susceptible to current than voltage as heat produced follows the formula \$I^2R\$. For AC devices, it is possible to destroy them with too high or too low a frequency.  These are just a few things that can happen, and the more you learn the more you can identify.  For many devices you can look up acceptable and ideal specifications.

That said, I've done some moderately risky power supply switches over the years, like using a PSP charger to power a 2wire brand router.  This is the only device I can remember operating poorly (after a few weeks it started showing intermittent problems so I switched the adaptor again and kept using it.)  The adaptor it is shipped with matches the Playstation Portable charger in ratings, but something about the way the PSP charger operates was not acceptable for the router.  The amount of effort put into providing the correct power should be proportional to how disappointed you will be if you let the smoke get out of it and the difficulty of keeping the smoke in that specific device.

> Let’s say I have a device, and on the box that goes into the wall it says “9V DC.” If I understand correctly, this means that it modulates the electricity coming in from the wall so that the appliance gets just 9V of electricity, and it also ensures that the current flows through as a direct current rather than an alternating one.

The device, referred to as an AC/DC or AC/AC adaptor, a wall wart, a power supply, does do what you describe, and it should be marked for:

-The output voltage, AC or DC, and the polarity of the connector.  Note that different converters function in different ways, as technology has been updated since their invention, and in addition to this, some loads(things being powered) are much more sensitive to the precise voltage they receive than others. This means that you have to be cautious about how much these devices vary from their ratings while operating normally.

For instance I have a 24v transformer that gives me 39V at no load(with nothing connected).  Once the device is drawing enough current, the voltage it gets from the transformer will drop to it's rated 24V, in the first instant a device is connected, it'll see 39V, so any device I connect must be able to withstand that.

-The rated output current, which is the highest output current that can be sustained from the device at it's rated voltage.

-Input ratings for voltage, frequency and max current.  I'll just include that these ratings describe the voltage and frequency the device must receive in order to operate as expected, and the most current it could be expected to draw.

Note that there is a good chance your device is actually marked with the precise input it should receive, and that this may vary a bit from the power supply that comes with it.

> Can I just take a 9V battery and use electrical tape and copper wires to connect it to this cable?

If you are referring to cutting the cable from the wall wart to use as a connector to the device, it would be better to find another cable with matching ratings (same size copper, same temperature and voltage insulation if relevant or marked, same connector).  As for means of connection, while you can make a circuit work by touching wires to things and taping them together, this is quite unnecessary as you could very cheaply solder or use proper mechanical connectors.  Inadequate connections can start fires.

As for the 9v battery, you may have just selected it as an example, but 9V batteries are expensive and have low performance for their size to boot, so I try to use them only in very low power low size applications.  Basically never.  It may be strongly preferable to use AA or lithium ion batteries and/or a voltage converter.  The other thing to note about batteries is that they are rated for a certain output voltage at a certain amount of current, but that's when they're fully charged, and the voltage decreases while discharging.  This is the opposite of the example above where a power supply has a transformer in it.  Whereas a 9V wall wart power supply with a transformer in it may show the device substantially higher voltages than 9v at low loads or for short periods of time, an alkaline battery rated at 9v will range from 9v down to 5.4v when depleted.  Rechargeable batteries marked 9v may actually start at voltages from 9.6V down to 7.2V The ratings appear the same, but in practice they are not.  Designers ensure that a device meant to operate on a 9V battery will operate over the expected range of voltages, and this means for a company to market a battery for that form factor, they simply need to ensure their voltage is within the accepted range.

> Do I need to be careful about which prong I tape to which wire (and what happens if it’s a 3-prong appliance instead of just 2)?

Ok, so you've definitely got the wrong idea.  A device meant to plug into the wall requires whatever your local mains voltage is.  If you wanted to battery power the device, you'd be looking at replacing the wall wart with a battery and/or voltage converter, rather than attaching a battery to the wall wart.  I strongly recommend that you avoid interacting with mains power without fully understanding it.

The prongs present on a 2 wire device are connections to either 2 lines of an electrical system or a line and a neutral, and the third prong, when present is the bonding wire or "ground".  Depending on where you live, a mains plug connection probably provides 110 or 220VAC at 50 or 60hz.  To make most devices that have this plug present work, you have to apply the correct AC voltage, at the correct AC frequency to those pins, from a source capable of sustaining the rated load of the wall wart.

So in this case you'd be looking at a battery bank and inverter (you've probably seen ones that give a line voltage connection off of a car battery).  You don't need to do this if you want to run off battery power because it would be easier to convert the voltage you have to the voltage you need directly.

> Or will I risk blowing my device?

You can probably gather from this and the other answer that there is definitely risk, but if you do enough research this can be mitigated and you could set something up.

> If I can’t use 9V, what is the maximum that I am able to use?

So you can see from all of this that a "nominal" 9V on a load is actually a point in the range of voltages the load can operate at, and for some loads this range is quite wide.  If you provide precisely 9V to a nominal 9V load, it should work fine, however:

A nominal 9V electronic power supply will typically produce very close to it's nominal voltage *when running at it's rated current*, but the fidelity with which it maintains that precise voltage, called load regulation, over the range of currents it can produce will vary with design and depend on the intended load.  If you have a working power supply you can use a voltmeter or preferably an oscilloscope to measure both it's fully loaded and no load output and use the information you gain to choose a working replacement.

As above a nominal 9V battery will start at some voltage and decrease to a point where it is considered to be depleted.  For rechargeable batteries it is important to stop drawing current from the battery at this point to prevent damage, and sometimes benefit to stopping short of it with little loss of storage.  The precise measured voltage at which you should stop varies with the current flowing through the battery during measurement.

If you can't find a battery or set of batteries that stays within the operable range during discharge or you find you have a device that operates best at a certain voltage (most devices not designed to use batteries vary in efficiency at minimum) you can use a voltage converter to change the voltage available from a preferred battery type into a constant voltage very close to the ideal.  Switching voltage converters are the most efficient, but none are 100% efficient, so you lose some power in changing voltage, however the power lost can be made up in efficiency gains or better overall functionality for some devices, or in some cases improve longevity, as some devices may appear to operate fine at a voltage that will slowly wear them out.  More voltage may make something "work better" at the cost of more heat being produced.

I won't go into heat sinks and fans and ambient temperature, but always be aware that nothing is 100% efficient, everything produces heat and almost everything "likes" to be kept cool.

Using a voltage converter also allows you great variety of battery selection, and a device has to be incredibly low power for this not to be an absolutely huge benefit, at least if you're comparing against a 9v battery or some other costly type.  Going from 9V to AA doubles the energy you can pack into the same space and massively reduces your cost/energy.  Going from AA to rechargables of some type can improve this again.

You must also either confirm that the device you are powering can handle out of range voltage (too low or too high) or prevent it from receiving it.  If all you can confirm that your device operates fine and won't be damaged by 9V or 0V, then you can still find a voltage converter that will run off the batteries you want and provide a steady 9V or shut down when the batteries no longer have enough power for the voltage converter to maintain it's output.

TLDR: You can't use a battery directly to provide 110/220VAC, but if you really want to power something from a battery you almost certainly can, though it may become complicated.

What you have right now is

[AC Mains]->[Unknown AC to 9VDC voltage converter]->[Device you want to power]

Unless you can be certain that the device will safely and efficiently operate as the battery discharges and shut down when depleted,

[Battery]->[Suitable DC to 9VDC voltage converter]->[Device you want to power]

and if you want you could go as far as

[Rechargable Battery w/ Protection and charging circuits]->[Suitable voltage converter]->[Device you want to power]

Comment: Captcha just asked me if I was a robot for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  The box going into the wall also has a maximum current written on it somewhere, and your battery may or may not be able to provide enough current to the device.  Also, you must be absolutely sure that the polarity of your patch job is correct (i.e., the correct battery lead going to the correct wire).  You might also thing about failure modes -- i.e., what's the worst thing that can happen if the voltage goes too low as the battery dies?

To be clear -- If the box is designed to be plugged into the wall, you CANNOT just glue a 9V Battery to the plug and have it work.  In that box there is circuitry that converts the mains AC signal (120V in the US) to 9V DC.  You would need to cut the wire that goes from the converter to your device, and replace the converter with a battery.

Comment: So I need to make sure that the battery provides enough voltage and enough current. Don’t I get a little wiggle room with that by adjusting the wires or kind of wires to have more or less resistance, and by keeping voltage constant, the current will go up as the resistance drops? As far as the polarity - I did ask that in my question; I assume that that’s why some devices have to be plugged in in a certain direction, while others can be flipped around with no problem?

Comment: @DonielF  I edited my answer to be clearer.  I think I misunderstood your question.  To answer your new question, the resistance of the wires is so small with respect to the resistance of your device that it is usually negligible.